# Connecting JDBC in JSTL

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to connect JDBC through JSTL. My Localhost ie:Xampp connection is also done still I'm getting this error which I'm not able to solve. Please help!
and I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2.Below is the code.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4AUp.png
[This is the error I'm getting ][1]

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="s" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <table bgcolor="orange">
                <tr>
                    <th>Book_Id</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t4"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Insert">
                        <input type="submit" name="b2" value="Update">
                        <input type="submit" name="b3" value="Delete"
</td> 
 </tr>
 </table>
  </form>
        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method='get'}">
            <c:set var="a" value="${param.t1}"/>
            <c:set var="b" value="${param.t2}"/>
            <c:set var="c" value="${param.t3}"/>
            <c:set var="d" value="${param.t4}"/>
            <s:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books" user="root" password=""/>
            <c:if test="${param.b1!=null}">
                <mysql:update datasource="${db}" sql="insert into book values {'${a}','${b}','${c}','${d}'}">
                </mysql:update>
                <c:out value="Record Inserted"/>
 </c:if>
            <c:if test="${param.b2!=null}">
                <mysql:update datasource="${db}" sql="Update book set bname='${b}',author='${c}',price='${d}' where book_id='${a}'">
                </mysql:update>
                <c:out value="Record Updated"/>
</c:if>
</c:if>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I also have added 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar' is the Webserver's lib directory.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.method='get'}">
```

should be:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='get'}">
```

Comment: Thank You @fgb it did connect but when I'm inserting or updating data via HTML form it's not reflecting on the database ie: on the Localhost site of XAMPP.

Comment: @NirajVora Also, 'get' should be 'post'